# Github Actions deployment for nodejs app to MS Azure takes 25 minutes, even if i only have one typo change - how can I improve this?

Tags: node.js, deployment, yaml, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a NodeJS app running on MS Azure as an Azure Web App. I have been using Github Actions to deploy new versions when new code is pushed to a develop/staging branch or the main branch on my Github remote repo.

This works. But it takes about 25 minutes at least to deploy, even if the code change is tiny, eg a single character in one .js file. The app is large and has many dependencies, but usually these are not changing and shouldn't need to be built and deployed each time. The logs suggest more than 10,000 files are being uploaded. Thus the build and deploy steps each take ages and this results in significant downtime for the live app on the Azure server.

Below is my (anonymised) current .yml file - as I say, this actually works, but it takes such a long time. Can anyone suggest a way of deploying just the changed files rather than rebuilding the whole app and deploying everything every time I need to make  minor adjustment? Or, to put it another way, can I get Github Actions to publish changes incrementally rather than rebuilding the whole app?

If this isn't possible, can anyone suggest a better way to deploy my NodeJS app to an Azure WebApp slot?

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      
      
      # Zip the build directory
      - name: Zip Release
        uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.6.1
        with:
          filename: release.zip
          path: .

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Staging'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Staging'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_*** }}
          package: release.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying one sample Nodejs express app in Azure and it got deployed in 7 mins 2 seconds:-

[image]

In order to run your Github action pipeline in an incremental mode, And to get the changes in the changed file via the previous and new commit Add the below code in your github workflow script:-

```yaml
- name: Archive changed files
        id: archive
        run: |
          git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }} | xargs zip release.zip
```

***My complete github action workflow code:-***

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install
        run: npm install
      
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build --if-present
      
      # You can also run tests here if needed
      
      - name: Archive changed files
        id: archive
        run: |
          git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }} | xargs zip release.zip

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Staging'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp984'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_2ECCD9239CC34B3990C26FADF7C6A }}
          package: release.zip
```

Apart from this an alternative is to use ARM templates to deploy your resource incrementally via Github actions.

You can refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-arm-template?pivots=platform-linux) that has the ARM template to deploy Web app, In Source control section you can use your Node-js application repository URL.

And then refer the github action workflow from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-github-actions?tabs=userlevel) and use this task:-

```yaml
- uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
      with:
        resourceGroupName: github-action-arm-rg
        template: ./azuredeploy.json
        deploymentMode: Incremental
```